# What are the open sets in $S^1$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I want to prove that for a continuous bijective function $f: [0,1) \to S^1$ such that $f^{-1}$ is not continuous, where $S^1=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb{R}^2 : x^2+y^2=1\}$.

> What are the open sets in $S^1$?

Comment: I presume you want to *find* a continuous bijective function $f:[0,1)\to S^1$ for which $f^{-1}$ is not continuous. By the way, the open sets on $S^1$ (unit circle) are just intersections of open sets in $\mathbb R^2$ with the unit circle, as per definition of subspace topology (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology)

Comment: The open sets are the intersections of the circle with open sets in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Show $f[[0,\frac12)]$ is not open in $S^1$ so $f$ is not an open map and so $f^{-1}$ is not continuous. $f(0)$ is not an interior point of it.

Comment: @DonThousand There are many more continuous bijections.